# placing a value in a variable and making it stay

Tags: linux

I have been trying to write a script where instead of using names I have done the obvious and saved time by assigning user ids and placed them in a variable. var1=usid
echo $usid shows that its done correct but I save, exit and when I reopen in the morning, the variable no longer exists. Is there a way to make it permanent?

Comment: What do you mean by "save"?

Comment: I suspect you are talking about environment variables. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use Unix `export`?

```
VAR=value
export VAR
```

The export command will mark each VAR for automatic export to the environment of subsequently executed commands i.e. make the local shell variable VAR global.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was missing. I was forgetting export.